# nested ng-repeat with json and rest api call back

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, http

I am trying to make a UI using list of product in a json(products.json) file on local and their availability in number from wp rest api call back in html(ionic) I have this:

`Controller`:

```
.controller('ShopCtrl', function($scope, $ionicActionSheet, BackendService, CartService, $http, $sce ) {


  $scope.siteCategories = [];
  $scope.cart = CartService.loadCart();

  $scope.doRefresh = function(){
      BackendService.getProducts()
      .success(function(newItems) {
        $scope.products = newItems;
        console.log($scope.products);
      })
      .finally(function() {
        // Stop the ion-refresher from spinning (not needed in this view)
        $scope.$broadcast('scroll.refreshComplete');
      });
  };


  $http.get("http://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/categories/").then(
    function(returnedData){
      $scope.siteCategories = returnedData.data;
      console.log($scope.siteCategories);
    }, function(err){
      console.log(err);
  });
```

`Template view`:

```
    <div ng-repeat = "product in products">
        <div class="item item-image" style="position:relative;">
          <img ng-src="{{product.image}}">
           <div ng-repeat = "siteCategory in siteCategories">-->
              <button class="button button-positive product-price" ng-click="addProduct(product)">
                  <p class="white-color product-price-price">post <b>{{siteCategory[$index].count}}</b></p>
              </button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="item ui-gradient-deepblue">
          <h2 class="title white-color sans-pro-light">{{product.title}} </h2>
        </div>

        <div class="item item-body">
          {{product.description}}
        </div>
    </div>
```

so how can I achieve that? I tried to use nested `ng-repeat` but it didn't work out.

Comment: What you are getting using `console.log($scope.siteCategories);`?

Comment: it returns back the array containing different categories and number as I need 
array[6] and inside array each it has its own methods, .name, .count(which i need), link, ...

Comment: Can you please include in your post a sample of what $scope.products and $scope.siteCategories look like?

Comment: Also, can you be more specific with what problem you are having? I'm guessing that your button text isn't working the way you expect?

Comment: the products.json file is like this which has $scope.products
[
    {
        "id" : 1,
        "title" : "AB",
        "description" : "Lorem ipsum dolor sit.",
        "image" : "sampledata/products/1.jpg",
        "price" : 10
    },
    {
        "id" : 2,
        "title" : "AC",
        "description" : "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consecte.",
        "image" : "sampledata/products/2.jpg",
        "price" : 100
    }, ...]
and the $scope.siteCategories is wprest api call back of categories in wordpress website

Comment: @ChrisNewman the problem now is when I run that code it creates 6*6 items, so it manipulates the number of products(which comes from http request) for each of the products that comes from products.json file